# Something wrong with my settings.json (VS Code) when I tried adding the Bracket Pair extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wanted to add the Bracket Pair extension on my VS Code but this line `"highlight-matching-tag.styles": {` has red underline on it. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the copy of all the code on my settings.json

```
{
    "diffEditor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "prettier.requireConfig": true,[`enter image description here`][1]
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "window.zoomLevel": -1
    "highlight-matching-tag.styles": {
        "opening": {
            "left": {
                "custom": {
                    "borderWidth": "0 0 0 3px",
                    "borderStyle": "solid",
                    "borderColor": "yellow",
                    "borderRadius": "5px",
                    "overviewRulerColor": "white"
            }
        },
                "right": {
                    "custom": {
                    "borderWidth": "0 5px 0 0",
                    "borderStyle": "solid",
                    "borderColor": "yellow",
                    "borderRadius": "5px",
                    "overviewRulerColor": "white"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[or if you want to see it visually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFfAK.png)

Answer (score 0):

there is no comma after the "window.zoom level": -1
once you put that there will be no error. It's a comma error in JSON